# Best way to deal with private scoped package used in monorepo

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

We have a monorepo that has multiple package inside it. One of these apps has a private scoped module required by it.

We do a single `yarn` at the root of the repo which in turn will install the modules for each package.

To save all teams having to maintain credentials for this private package, we ideally don't want to issue them - and instead find some way that this module can be skipped for anyone who can't install it.

I have tried adding it as an optional dependency but that seems to still error out.

I have tried just manually installing the module - but then running `yarn` will remove it and requires it to then be added again.

How can we achieve this?